# QGIS Spatialite import fails when data is projected

Tags: qgis, error, spatialite, import, database

I'm trying to import a shapefile into a spatialite database via drag & drop. This works fine while the data is in a geographic coordinate system, but I need to do some measurements and therefore need projected data. However, I get an error when I try to import the projected data. The error message isn't very helpful either. How can I solve this?

[image]

I also tried the DB manager and geht this error:

[image]

Spatialite-GUI: no "Map Preview" option

[image]

EPSG 54004:

[image]

EPSG 3857:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to import this data via spatialite-gui or QGIS DB manager with proper CRS? Do you have any errors?

Comment: with the DB manager I get another error message (added screenshot above), with the GUI I could import the data but when I want to display it in QGIS I just see a blank canvas (I'm probably doing something wrong here, I'm not too familiar with spatialite)

Comment: please add more info about your shapefile (geometry type, source coordinate system, layer extent). Can you add and plot this shp directly in QGIS? Have checked it for topology errors or/and import other files?

Comment: I tried with different geometry types (point and polygon), the coordinate system is World Mercator (EPSG: 54004), layer extent (of the polygon dataset): xMin,yMin -20037508.34,-8246435.55 : xMax,yMax 20037508.34,18386391.71
I can add the shapefiles as such to QGIS without a problem! I don't think it can be the topology as the point shapefile didn't work either.

Comment: I just tried it with data in other projected coordinate systems, the problem only occurs for coordinate systems like World Mercator, Miller World, Mollweide etc. It does not occur for regional coordinate systems. However, I need to present a world map, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: to get more info about the error, you can use qgis log window. You find it under View->Panels->Log Messages [Ansicht->Bedienfelder->Protokoll in German, ...]

Comment: There is no message about this error in the log...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPSG 54004 seemed to be the source of the problem, EPSG 3857 worked fine for dragging and dropping the shapefile in the spatialite database, it also worked within the DB manager!

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest to import into the spatialite DB using spatialite-gui. After the shapefile is imported you can see a quick view of the layer directly within ppatialite-gui by right-click on the "geometry" column and choose "Map preview". This will show you if the layer is correctly imported, even before you switch back to QGIS.
Be sure to select the correct projection in the :Load Shapefile" window.

Comment: The import into spatialite via the gui works without errors, but when I want to add the data to QGIS everything is blank. Also I can't fing the "Map Preview", the only options I see when right clicking the geometry column are "Refresh", "Check geometries" and "Get SRID".

Comment: Wait a moment with QGIS. In spatialite-gui, if you right-click on the table (layer) and choose "Edit table rows" what do you get in the data pane on the right? Again, in Spatialite-gui, expand the layer, and do a right click on the geometry. There you should be able to choose Map preview.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the spatialite gui in the post above!

Comment: Have you set the SRID inside the spatialite GUI? For World Mercator, try EPSG:3857.

Comment: AFAIK there's no EPSG:54004. Please drop the countries_p table, then reimport, as AndreJ suggests, with EPSG:3857. Also be sure you **know in advance** whether the original data is polygon or point, and import as the correct geometry.

Comment: There is a EPSG: 54004 (see Screenshot above), however I tried the EPSG 3857 (Pseudo Mercator) and I get a really weird result when projecting (see Screenshot above). I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: Also what should I set for SRID?

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect comment regarding 54004. It's a deprecated definition, but you're right: it still is listed. The problem in the screen shot(the strip across the world) seems to be due to polygons (Alaska) crossing over to < -180 deg. The wrapping at the edge of the map is causing that funny display. Is it possible to share the source of the data?

Comment: Oh my god it finally worked! So the weird strip across the world was my fault, I moved that to make the map look nicer but after projecting it, it causes this error. However, I downloaded the original file again from Natural Earth (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/), saved it in EPSG 3857 and then I can just drag and drop it into the spatialite database, also works with DB manager, I'm still having trouble with the GUI but don't really need it for now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cheers, glad to help.